# Почему javascript массив пустой?

Tags: javascript

Вот пример из реального (пока не рабочего) кода:

```js
var a = new Array();


a["www.site.ru"] = "url1";
a["www.site2.ru"] = "url2";

console.log(a);
console.log("Длинна массива: "+a.length);
```

---

В консоли Mozilla Firefox вижу вот такую картину...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос почему 0, ведь в массиве есть элементы?

Answer (score 5):

Потому что это хэш-таблица(ассоциативный массив), а не просто массив. Нужно сделать так чтобы получить 2(количество ключей):

```
Object.keys(a).length
```

Вместо:

```
a.length
```

Пример:

```js
var a = new Array();

a["www.site.ru"] = "url1";
a["www.site2.ru"] = "url2";

alert("Ключей в ассоциативном массиве: "+Object.keys(a).length);
```

Answer (score 2):

Потому что добавление в массив элементов выполняется с помощью команды [push](http://javascript.ru/Array/push). Роль ассоциативных массивов в Javascript выполняют [объекты](https://learn.javascript.ru/object).

Answer (score 0):

В массиве использую индексы

```
var a = new Array();

a["www.site.ru"] = "url1";
a["www.site2.ru"] = "url2";

console.log(a);
console.log("Длинна массива: "+a.length);
```

То чего вы хотите достичь, достигается объектами

```
var a = { "www.site.ru": "url1", "www.site2.ru": "url2"}
```